# passing controller parameter swing java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

According to the MVC model, is it safe and "correct" to pass controller through mainFrame to subclasses? 
I try to implement certain functions(like save file, open file) and I so far I had them inside mainFrame class of a program which is so far the only class having access to the controller. 
Now I decided to use Command Strategy Pattern but I'd have to pass the controller as a parameter to the subclass to use it(Controller it's used to access model and save object).

Comment: Look also at Mediator pattern. Wiki has example similar to your situation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25502552/230513).

Comment: Yes and no, this might result in a god controller which isn't what you want, so instead, you might have a number of child controllers (which could reference the main controller as required), as an idea