# Adjusting Coordinates Given Angle / Window Size in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, trigonometry, graphics2d

So this may be a fairly simple question, however I've been writing this code for over 8 hours so my brain is slightly pooped. Basically, I have a frame that looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkbD1.jpg)

If you'll excuse my crude drawing, I was wondering about the maths. Given the angle theta, what I want to do is, given a specific Point object, that will be the bullet I shoot, how do I adjust the x/y coordinates in parallel to move along that given angle? There is a window size of 700x500 inside the JFrame. I'll post the code in a pastebin if it is quite necessary but I felt that this question was purely arithmetic (sin/cos/tan) related.

Basically I have this:

```
        if(pinballAngle > 90){
            pinballCoordinate.x+=(pinballAngle/3);
            pinballCoordinate.y-=20;
        }
        else if(pinballAngle < 90){
            pinballCoordinate.x+=(pinballAngle/3);
            pinballCoordinate.y-=20;
        }
        else{
            pinballCoordinate.y-=20;
        }
```

So pinballCoordinate is the Point object that I am trying to adjust given the angle of theta, that is the 'gun' that shoots the pinball. The 'pinballAngle' variable is the angle of the gun.

Comment: So you're asking how to work out sines and cosines in Java?

Comment: So, the question could boil down to a linear path following problem.  That is, you have a start point, you have an angle and you want to follow a path away from the start point.  Here I'm falling back to calculating a point on a circle to generate my target point and then I just need to follow a straight line between those points :P - It's probably a little convoluted, but I fall back on things I know how to solve when presented with issues like this ;)

Comment: See the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4550667/230513).

Answer (score 0):

first, you will need your angle in radian

```
int speed = 20; // the speed of the bullet

double rad = pinballAngle * 2 * Math.PI / 360;
pinballCoordinate.x += (int) ( Math.cos(rad)*speed );
pinballCoordinate.y += (int) ( Math.sin(rad)*speed );
```

You will probably need to use the opposite in x or y, replace with some `-=` where it is needed.

the Math documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: `-=` is not needed, as sine and cosine already produce the correct positive/negative values.

Comment: You'll probably need `-=` for `y` but `+=` for `x`.

Comment: @DavidWallace that's true in the case that they are correcting for the inverted y-axis used by most layout/drawing utilities. The geometries are, in these cases, merely flipped vertically, such that rotations are represented in the opposite direction.

Comment: @GameGibu Yes, and it also depends on what pinballAngle means in the OP source code, aka if 0° is the left or right direction (in the picture, it's the left direction, so `-=` for x)

Comment: How do you determine the vertical (y) or horizontal (x) distance when all the parameters (sides) of triangle are unknown?

Comment: @NimitPatel what do you mean ? obviously you can't determine a unique triangle when no side lenght is fixed. Here, the hypotenuse is arbitrarily set to 20